# Elixir - ETS with custom equals/hash function

Tags: set, elixir, ets

In Java, the equals/hash functions can be customised simply by overriding/implementing methods on a class.

This is very useful when you want to customise uniqueness of your class - so that you can check for 'duplicates' in a set easily.

How would you do the same thing in Elixir, specifically with ETS?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible. If you explain your use case further someone might be able to suggest an alternate solution that works with ETS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what I need to do is by making a unique hash function (that can return any type). There should only be one unique output of this hash function per unique input.

Then you can store the {hash, val} tuples:

```
table = :ets.create(:table, [])
:ets.insert(table, {hash(val), val})
:ets.lookup(table, hash(val))
```